# Kendo UI Text-Binding on Buttons and Links

Tags: text, mvvm, binding, kendo-ui

I actually thought this would be a simple task but I can't get it to work.
Here's the scenario:

I have a view-model which has a label-object that contains various Strings.

```
label: {
    'title': app.options.localize('products'),
    'leftTabButton': app.options.localize('menu'),
    'rightTabButton': app.options.localize('scan'),
    'leftDetailButton': app.options.localize('back'),
    'rightDetailButton': app.options.localize('save')
}
```

Now I have a corresponding view which binds to that model and tries to bind these labels to some buttons.

```
<div id="navbar" data-role="navbar">
    <a data-align="left" data-bind="Text: label.leftDetailButton"></a>
    <span data-role="view-title" data-bind="text: label.title"></span>
    <a data-role="button" data-align="right" data-bind="Text: label.rightDetailButton"></a>
</div>
```

But neither binding to `<a>` nor binding to `data-role="button"` (which is a widget) succeeds.
I always get: "Uncaught Error: The Text binding is not supported by the a element"
I also tried to do a custom binding... doesn't work either.

```
kendo.data.binders.widget.buttonText = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
    init: function(widget, bindings, options) {
    widget.element[0].innerText = bindings.buttonText.path;
}
});
```

While `bindings.buttonText.path` is the path to the string inside the view-model I don't know how to tell it which model to use or where to provide the reference to the model.

Any Suggestions what to do?

Answer (score 3):

Did you realize that you have typed `Text` instead of `text` for both `<a>`? Try changing it!
Also, I think that you also missed in the backbutton to specify the role `data-role="backbutton"`

Comment: Thx for the reply. Honestly I didn't realize that typo. Nevertheless, changing Text to text doesn't affect the result. Still the error. Regarding the backbutton: I want a button, not a backbutton ;)

Comment: Please, check in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/pAYAd/2/). It works for me

Comment: Btw: For the first `<a>` if you want a `button` you have to say it ;-). You forgot `data-role="button"`

Comment: Indeed you fiddle works. I "fiddled" around a bit but cant really think of whats wrong with my code. The only thing that might be possible is a timing issue (Im binding before an object is ready or sth like this). The differences I noticed so far: I use declarative binding `data-model="bound"` and the object containing the labels is an observable. BTW: I figured out how to use custom bindings. With such a binding it works flawlessly. That's why I think it's a timing thing since I register the binding at the very first start of the app.

Comment: And I didnt forget `data-role`, I was trying to bind to a simple `<a>` element to see if this works. because this is an element and the button is a widget. If I rename the binding in your fiddle it still says cannot bind to element `a instead` of `widget button`. Strange things...

Comment: Do you have a fiddle that fails? May I take a look into it? Relative to declarative binding just to say that there is a _little_ problem in your case that is that you have to define `bound` before initializing the application but you have to have the application `app` initialized before because you use `app.options` in the bound => deadlock. The only way to avoid this is do not use declarative binding but programmatic **after** having the application initialized and hence `app.options.localize` existing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20246/discussion-between-emiliano-bartolome-and-d2ux)